# Z3 Getting FuncInterp as Null

Tags: java, z3, smt

I'm using the Z3 Java API to parse an SMT file; when I call `s.getModel()`, where `s` is a solver, I'm able to print the model correctly as follows:

```
(define-fun O_STUDENT () (Array Int STUDENT_TupleType)
  ((as const (Array Int STUDENT_TupleType))
  (STUDENT_TupleType _ID__12345 _NAME__Bourikas _DEPT_uNAME__Music 29)))
(define-fun O_DEPARTMENT () (Array Int DEPARTMENT_TupleType)
  ((as const (Array Int DEPARTMENT_TupleType))
  (DEPARTMENT_TupleType _DEPT_uNAME__Music _BUILDING__BUILDING_u5 50000.0)))
```

However, when I try to get the `FuncInterp` for `O_STUDENT` array, I get a `null`. I'm using the following to extract that value:

```
if (s.check() == Status.SATISFIABLE) {
            Model m = s.getModel();
            FuncDecl arrayDep = m.getConstDecls()[0];
            System.out.println(m.getFuncInterp(arrayDep));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case: arrays are a little special because there are constants, but their models are functions (see e.g. https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/java/Model.java#L88).

Models may not contain assignments for all variables - if one is missing, it means that you're free to choose any value you like. If you don't like that, you can enable model completion and Z3 will choose for you.

Comment: But in this case, when I print the model, I get the interpretations for the two arrays; however I don't get one using `m.getFuncInterp`.

Comment: Can you try `m.getConstInterp`? At least one of them should give you something, otherwise please file a bug at https://github.com/z3prover/z3/issues

Comment: Using `m.getConstInterp` gives `com.microsoft.z3.Z3Exception: Non-zero arity functions and arrays have FunctionInterpretations as a model. Use getFuncInterp`.

Comment: I've raised an issue on GitHub regarding this; is it reproducible on your end?

Comment: Thanks, the bug was fixed on GitHub.